# Segfault calling shared object from python in a library ported from Win32 to Linux

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

I have library, ported from Windows, that I call from Python using ctypes. This combination has worked for me on 32 and 64 bit Windows, using python 2.7 and 3.5, but segfaults after porting to my current Linux environment, Ubuntu 17.04 with gcc 6.3 and python 3.5.

The library has two callbacks with slightly different signatures. The first operates as expected, but the second segfaults in the ctypes library.

The callback signatures in C are:

```
typedef void (*StatusCallback)(void* ctxt, enum STATUS status, void* data);
typedef void (*MsgCallback)(void* ctxt, enum STREAM stream, DataMsg* msg);
```

And are defined using ctypes as

```
STATUSCB = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p, c_uint, c_void_p)
MSGCB = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_void_p, c_uint, POINTER(DataMsg))
```

Its the second callback that is failing and it differs from the first in it's last parameter which is a POINTER(DataMsg). In C DataMsg is defined as:

```
typedef struct DataItem
{
    uint8_t* name;
    enum DATATYPE type;
    uint8_t* unit;
    uint32_t numValues;
    void* values;
    enum DATASTATUS* valueStatuses;
    uint32_t numChildren;
    struct DataItem* children;
}
DataItem;

typedef struct DataMsg
{
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint32_t numItems;
    struct DataItem* items;
}
DataMsg;
```

And in python:

```
DataItemPtr = POINTER(DataItem)

DataItem._fields_ = [
    ('name', c_char_p),
    ('type', c_uint),
    ('unit', c_char_p),
    ('numValues', c_uint),
    ('values', c_void_p),
    ('valueStatuses', POINTER(c_uint)),
    ('numChildren', c_uint),
    ('children', DataItemPtr) ]

DataMsg._fields_ = [
    ('timestamp', c_ulonglong),
    ('numItems', c_uint),
    ('items', DataItemPtr) ]
```

Here's a stacktrace obtained while running under gdb:

```
Thread 5 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffec7ba700 (LWP 17002)]
0x00007ffff66b4b8e in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff66b4b8e in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#1  0x00007ffff66b4f4c in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#2  0x00007ffff66b57b7 in ffi_closure_unix64_inner ()
   from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#3  0x00007ffff66b5c10 in ffi_closure_unix64 ()
   from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#4  0x00007fffe801972c in HandleSysDescriptor (Channel=0x7fffe000f3a0, 
    channel=0x7fffe000f570, flow_id=2, dict=0x7fffe0024368, msg=0x7fffe0020470)
    at /home/michael/dev//linux/source/ARCDevKit/SapphireReceive.c:471
#5  0x00007fffe8018fb2 in HandleMessage (channel=0x7fffe000f570, flow_id=2, 
    dict=0x7fffe0024368, msg=0x7fffe0020470)
    at /home/michael/dev//linux/source/ARCDevKit/SapphireReceive.c:290
#6  0x00007fffe8024860 in process_item (channel=0x7fffe000f570, flow_id=2, 
    dict=0x7fffe0024368, mesg=0x7fffe0020470)
    at /home/michael/dev//linux/source/SbxCLib/sbxc/usnet/us_tcp_channel_connection.c:97
```

I tried replacing the POINTER(DataMsg) with c_void_p to see if I could get callback to enter the python code, but the same error occurred. I was worried about the size of the enums vs the c_uint's used for the enum argument types, but it works for the first callback, just not the second.

It works when called directly from C which is another reason to suspect the way I am using ctypes.

It also works under a number of different permutations under Windows with a number of different VS versions (2005, 2008, 2013, 2015) so I suspect some sort of difference in the handling of pointers, enums, or ints, but I have not tracked down anything specific yet.

Comment: A few things that popped out at me: `c_char_p` is for null-terminated strings, not for arbitrary `uint8_t*`s, and the typedefs for `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` might not be what you're expecting them to be.

Comment: Also, the underlying types of your enums are implementation-defined.

Comment: sizeof() on the c side gives 4 bytes for the enums. I don't know how to check the size of c_uint and I've seen some conflicting comments on forums on what to exect, is there a way to check?

Comment: Are you sure you applied `sizeof` to the enum types themselves, and not the enum values? If you have `enum foo {X};`, `sizeof X` and `sizeof (enum foo)` can be different values, because `X` has type `int`, not type `enum foo`.

Comment: `ctypes` has [`ctypes.sizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.sizeof) to find the size of a ctypes type.

Comment: The uint8_t* are in fact null terminated strings which is why they are declared that way on the python side. The values are pulled out of another library that declares them as uint8_t, does ctypes expect a particular kind of char (unsigned/signed)?

Comment: ctypes uses whatever kind of char the compiler it was compiled on uses.

Comment: I was using sizeof on a value, but in this case sizeof the enum and c_uint all return 4. I hadn't realized they could be different, very interesting!

Comment: It looks like the segfault happens in `_CallPythonObject`. Please use the debug build, `python3-dbg`.

Comment: For portability, use `c_uint32` and `c_uint64`. Also, assuming that an enum type is stored as an `unsigned int` is generally fine -- unless it's declared with values that are negative or won't fit in an `int`.

Comment: You don't show how you're using the `MSGCB` function pointer type. Are you being careful to keep the instantiated callback referenced when the library calls it?

Comment: I was stripping this down to a smaller example and found that I was using MSGCB to wrap the python function twice. Something like:

    self.msgcb = MSGCB(my_msgcb)

Then a little later in the code calling the shared object:

     wrapper.method(MSGCB(self.msgcb), ...)

So inadvertently wrapping the method twice. I'm still scratching my head over why it works on Windows and failed on Linux.

Thanks for looking this over!